# Tensorflow adam optimizer ValueError "Error: None values not supported."

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am attempting to write a tensorflow script for training an image segmentation using the graph structure of the `FCN_8s` model. I'm adapting the code from some online tutorials, and there is clearly something (or many things) I am doing wrong. When I try and define the optimizer using adam optimizer (see below) I get a `valueError` indicating `Tried to convert 'values' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.`

Here is how I am initializing the optimizer and defining the loss function, which is called later in a tf.session()

```
     cross_entropies = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=flat_logits,
                                                             labels=flat_labels)

     cross_entropy_sum = tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropies)
     with tf.variable_scope("adam_vars"):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
        gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=cross_entropy_sum)
        for grad_var_pair in gradients:
            current_variable = grad_var_pair[1]
            current_gradient = grad_var_pair[0]
            gradient_name_to_save = current_variable.name.replace(":", "_")
            tf.summary.histogram(gradient_name_to_save, current_gradient)
```

Calling `tf.trainable_variables` shows that there are variables. I think the issue might be with the `cross_entropy_sum`? Using `get_shape(cross_entropy_sum)` returns `()`, but if I use the `keepdims` option, the shape is `(1,)` but I get the same error.

Here is the error traceback:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py:198:
>   retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
>   updating: Use the retry module or similar alternatives. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 510, in _apply_op_helper
>       preferred_dtype=default_dtype)   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 214, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 421, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.") ValueError: None values not supported.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 524, in _apply_op_helper
>       values, as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 214, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 421, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.") ValueError: None values not supported.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "P:\macro and programming
>   files\TFpy\TFcarcassimageseg3.py", line 252, in 
>       tf.summary.histogram(gradient_name_to_save, current_gradient)    File
>   "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py",
>   line 196, in histogram
>       tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py",
>   line 308, in _histogram_summary
>       "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)   File "C:\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 528, in _apply_op_helper
>       (input_name, err)) ValueError: Tried to convert 'values' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.

I'm out of my depth here, but I would appreciate any pointers in resolving this error, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`None values not supported.` This happens if you use a TensorFlow instruction on a variable containing none. I used `if g is not None:` as `apply_gradients(...)` is using it!